# error installing latex-sketch-plugin while executing npm run watch

Tags: node.js, git, npm, sketch-3, sketchapp

I am having error installing [latex-sketch-plugin](https://github.com/heytitle/latex-sketch-plugin). I don't have a complete idea how to install this plugin but I need it for my thesis as I have to make some diagrams that will need mathematical equations written as well. So basically, I have node package manager

```
amar@admin:~$ npm -v
5.4.2
```

and I cloned the [latex-sketch-plugin](https://github.com/heytitle/latex-sketch-plugin) repo using `git clone` into sketch plugin folder i.e `~/Library/Application Support/com.bohemiancoding.sketch3/Plugins`

but when I execute `npm run watch` I  get the following error

```
   amar@admin:~$ npm run watch
    npm ERR! path /Users/amar/package.json
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno -2
    npm ERR! syscall open
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/amar/package.json'
    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent 

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/amar/.npm/_logs/2017-11-08T04_14_49_190Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says /Users/amar/package.json cannot be found. Looks like you ran the npm command in /Users/amar folder. Please run in the folder where you cloned the project, so npm can find package.json